# Angular 2 - invalid external dependency requirements

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, ng2-bootstrap, angular-seed

On my local environment it still works. But on continues integration server fails.
I think this happen after install of ng2-bootstrap.

```
    17-Oct-2016 18:33:57 npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/compiler@2.1.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
    17-Oct-2016 18:33:57 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.1.0 wants @angular/compiler@2.1.0
    17-Oct-2016 18:33:57 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ng2-bootstrap@1.1.14 wants @angular/compiler@^2.0.0
    17-Oct-2016 18:33:57 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.0 wants @angular/compiler@^2.0.0
    17-Oct-2016 18:33:57 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 wants @angular/compiler@2.0.2
    17-Oct-2016 18:33:57 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-server@2.1.0 wants @angular/compiler@2.1.0
```

This is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es-module-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.15.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.13",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.38",
    "zone.js": "0.6.25"   
  }
```

Please, help me to debug and resolve dependencies.

**UPD.** On the local folder with empty angular2-seed project and mentioned above dependencies:

[image]

Comment: It looks like ng-bootstrap has a peer dependency on "@angular/compiler" which is a very strong constraint (normally you would like to AoT your application and don't use compiler during runtime). You might want to check alternative implementation (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) that correctly handles peer dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, I'll will try this in solution